# I want to check if try again button exist if it does it should repeatdly click on it

Tags: json, automation, conditional-statements

I am using below code to check if try again button exist if it exist it should click on it and move on and it should repeatedly check if try again exist or not on screen and click on it but if it doesnt exiet on the first it should go on with other things below is the code i am using but giving me error

```
[
  {
    "Command": "open",
    "Target": "xyz",
    "Value": "",
    "Description": "Attempt to load the URL"
  },
  {
    "Command": "while",
    "Target": "verifyElementPresent(//button[@class='primary try-again'])",
    "Value": "",
    "Description": "While 'Try Again' button exists"
  },
  {
    "Command": "click",
    "Target": "//button[@class='primary try-again']",
    "Value": "",
    "Description": "Click the 'Try Again' button"
  },
  {
    "Command": "waitForElementNotPresent",
    "Target": "//button[@class='primary try-again']",
    "Value": "",
    "Description": "Wait for 'Try Again' button to disappear"
  },
  {
    "Command": "endWhile",
    "Target": "",
    "Value": "",
    "Description": "End while loop"
  },
  {
    "Command": "type",
    "Target": "id=ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_loginUserNameTextBox",
    "Value": "username@gmail.com",
    "Description": "Enter username"
  },
  {
    "Command": "type",
    "Target": "id=ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_loginPasswordTextBox",
    "Value": "Password",
    "Description": "Enter password"
  },
  {
    "Command": "clickAndWait",
    "Target": "id=ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_loginButton",
    "Value": "",
    "Description": "Click login button"
  }
]
```

I am getting error in while condition if the try again button doesnt exist at the first time